# how to use light shade of selected color variable in flutter

Tags: flutter

Here i have created a simple demo for using color shade of Color variable

I have a container with a color and and a center text which color should be lighter shade of container's color

here is my code

```
List<Color> colorlist=[
  Colors.red,
  Colors.orange,
  Colors.greenAccent,
  Colors.blue,
  Colors.yellow,
];

class HomeScreen6 extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen6({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: colorlist.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return Container(
          height: 100,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: colorlist[index],
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Sample',style: TextStyle(
              color: colorlist[index].shade200,//here i want light shade of container's color
            ),),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your list from `List<Color>` to `List<ColorSwatch>`, and then style your `Text` widget like this:

```
style: TextStyle(
  color: colorlist[index][200],                        
),
```

Btw `Colors.greenAccent` is not a valid `ColorSwatch` value.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggested following code but i dont think its a good way of coding

```
Map<Color,Color> colorlist={
  Colors.red:Colors.red.shade100,
  Colors.orange:Colors.orange.shade100,
  Colors.greenAccent:Colors.greenAccent.shade100,
  Colors.blue:Colors.blue.shade100,
  Colors.yellow:Colors.yellow.shade100,
};


class HomeScreen6 extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen6({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: colorlist.keys.length,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return Container(
          height: 100,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: colorlist.keys.toList()[index],
          child: Center(
            child: Text('Sample',style: TextStyle(
              color: colorlist.values.toList()[index],
            ),),
          ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```